# BSOD when using kmeans algo with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bsod

I'm currently doing a classifer for dog breed old fashioned way, using SIFT descriptor and doing a kmeans to get a bag of visual words.
My dataset comes from the Stanford Dogs Dataset which contains approximately 20 000 images. I'm using the sift detect and compute from opencv :

```
descriptor_list = []
def descriptor(df):
for img in df.img:
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    keypoint, descriptor = sift.detectAndCompute(img, None)
    for k in range(descriptor.shape[0]):
        descriptor_list.append(descriptor[k].astype('int32'))
return descriptor_list
```

Then I turned in into a panda dataframe :

[image]

First as you can see, the memory usage is 2.5GB, is it normal even with 2millions+ entries ?

Then, when I do kmeans with 500 cluster, I got a BSOD, with stop code : WIN32K_POWER_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT.

Computer specs :

- Windows 10 (version 18362.778)
- WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)
- CPU i7-8565U
- RAM 16GB

Software version :

- Python : 3.5
- Opencv : 4.3.0
- jupyter core     : 4.6.3
- jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
- qtconsole        : 4.7.2
- ipython          : 7.9.0
- ipykernel        : 5.2.0
- jupyter client   : 6.1.2
- nbconvert        : 5.6.1
- ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
- nbformat         : 5.0.5
- traitlets        : 4.3.3

Thanks for your responses !